# Split multi-line cell in an Wikitable based R dataframe & keep 'category' column

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, multiline

I have a dataframe of the format:

```
Location       Date
         1 - 10/10/2015
         2 - 11/10/2015 
Place    3 - 12/10/2015
         5 - 12/10/2015
NxtPlace 4 - 12/10/2015
```

...

The 2nd column has lots of multi-line rows containing dates (of events), the first column has their location and the nrow is equal to the n of locations rather than of eventdates.

I'd like to:
 1. Have a row per event
 2. Repeat the location next to each matched date

The actual dataset is like the one you read in using the below code, and is (I think) a fairly common format particularly in Wiki tables:

```
library(XML)
WikiMeets <- readHTMLTable(doc="http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Meetup/UK/Footer_list")
WikiMeets <- as.character(WikiMeets[[1]]) #it'll save as factor otherwise
```

I was trying to just write a loop or apply to run through each row, and gsub each "\n" in the 2nd column for the value of the 1st + some commas, e.g. ",London," then just splitting the 2nd column would be easy.  I feel like that's probably a pretty inelegant solution (which I'm not getting right anyway), I had a look at ddply and `split` but struggled there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
NewData <- ddply(messy_table, .(Location), 
  function(x) data.frame(WDate=str_split(x$Date, "\n")[[1]]))
```

This gives the data the correct form:

```
Location       WDate
Place    1 - 10/10/2015
Place    2 - 11/10/2015 
Place    3 - 12/10/2015
NxtPlace 5 - 12/10/2015
NxtPlace 4 - 12/10/2015
```

...

I have to say, I don't quite understand how it works(!) (I played a bit) but it does.